# Flutter: my flutter app is crashed on launch after I implement google interstitial ads

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, gadinterstitial

I am building my first flutter app. I try to implement google interstitial add in my app.
But the app is crashing on launch. I used Android emulator to launch the app.

I added this in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

and in build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mando.minu_app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        targetSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the crash log? Without it, it will be very hard to help you out. Also, sharing the relevant code where the crash originates from will be helpful.

Comment: oh. I fixed it. There is no error log. the app just not open. I added some dependencies in build.gradle and it work